# Timer Task suspend when device going to sleep

Tags: android, timertask, foreground-service

I'm developing timer app like focus to do and to achieve this I used a foreground service and timer task within it.

now when when device is screen off timer task no longer emitted.

and after a little when device screen turns on timer task emits immediately

my timer interval is set to 100 ms, but updating the UI every 1 second.
Also the app was excluded from battery saving.

my custom timer task class:

```
     abstract class CustomTimer @JvmOverloads constructor(
     private val totalTime: Long,
     private val interval: Long,
     private val delay: Long = 0
     ) :
Timer("PreciseCountdownTimer", true) {
private var task: TimerTask
private var startTime: Long = -1
private var timeLeft: Long = 0
private var restart = false
private var wasCancelled = false
private var isDisposed = false
private var wasStarted = false

init {
    task = buildTask(totalTime)
    isDisposed = false
}

private fun buildTask(totalTime: Long): TimerTask {
    return object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            if (startTime < 0 || restart) {
                startTime = scheduledExecutionTime()
                timeLeft = totalTime
                restart = false
            } else {
                timeLeft = totalTime - (scheduledExecutionTime() - startTime)
                if (timeLeft <= 0) {
                    this.cancel()
                    wasCancelled = true
                    startTime = -1
                    Log.d("shower", "run: ")
                    onFinished()
                    return
                }
            }

            onTick(timeLeft)
        }
    }
}

fun getTimeLeft() = timeLeft
fun start() {
    wasStarted = true
    isDisposed = false
    this.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, interval)
}

fun stop() {
    wasCancelled = true
    task.cancel()
    onStop()
}

fun restart() {
    if (!wasStarted) {
        start()
    } else if (wasCancelled) {
        wasCancelled = false
        task = buildTask(totalTime)
        start()
    } else {
        restart = true
    }
}


fun isDisposed() = isDisposed
fun pause() {
    wasCancelled = true
    task.cancel()
    onPaused()
}

fun updateWithNewTime(time : Long){
    task.cancel()
    task = buildTask(time)
    startTime = -1
    start()
}

fun resume() {
    wasCancelled = false
    isDisposed = false
    task = buildTask(timeLeft)
    startTime = -1
    start()
    onResumed()
}

// Call this when there's no further use for this timer
fun dispose() {
    this.cancel()
    this.purge()
    isDisposed = true
}

abstract fun onTick(timeLeft: Long)
abstract fun onFinished()
abstract fun onPaused()
abstract fun onResumed()
abstract fun onStop()
```

}

I created log file which prove my assertion to timer not working in sleep mode. It is not emitted from second 3 until second 16 and then emits very fast in second 16 and 17... log is updated every 1 second.

[image]

Comment: To my knowl she, if the device is in sleep mode your app is no longer the front most app, thus a foreground service will be stopped. So you need to keep the screen on or implement a background service. Remember to exclude your app from battery saving (needs to be done by the user).

Comment: @Robert Thanks, in the log file the service is not shutted down yet, background service is restricted by the Android os now.

Comment: When I say "stopped" this does not have to mean the service is killed. It may just get no CPU time by the scheduler or the amount of CPU time is limited to a smaller time span so that the CPU is not interrupted from deep sleep several times a second.

Comment: @Robert I have a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446935/coroutine-launched-from-foreground-service-getting-paused) problem. The foreground service is paused after 30s. You can go to "App Info" -> "Battery Usage" -> "Allow background activity" to fix it, but I don't know how to solve the problem programmatically.

Comment: @BPDev Disabling battery saving is AFAIK only disablable by the user. This is by design. Other measures on programming level are summarized on https://dontkillmyapp.com